# Align <HR> to right in IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, microsoft-edge

Trying to align a handful of `<hr>` elements to the right on this page.
In IE/Edge, the `<hr>` elements align left in every case.

I am using `<hr class="hr-right">`

```
.hr-right {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

I have tried to use floats and clears, but I end up with the `<hr>` being displayed like a float image inside the paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want elements to align-right in a flex container use:

```
margin-left: auto
```

not

```
margin-right: 0;
```

Flex auto margins work by consuming all available free space.

So `margin-left: auto` will consume all space to the left of the item, pinning it to the right edge.

More details here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Thank you, while this technically breaks it in chrome for me, all I needed to change it to for both browsers was margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0;

Comment: My answer is based on the code posted in your question. Consider posting a working example for a more in-depth review.